# How to use an operator in where clause with an optional include?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have the following Model:

```
AuthorModel.hasMany(BookModel);
BookModel.belongsTo(AuthorModel);
```

Some authors have no books.

I want to select an author whose name or title of one of his books matches the search string.

I can achieve this with the following statement, but only for authors with books in their BookModel

```
       Author.findOne({
         include: [{
            model: Book,
            where: {
              [Op.or]: [
                  {'$author.name$': 'search string'},
                  { title: 'search string'}
                 ]
               },
             }]
           })
```

This gives me more or less the following `mysql` query:

```
SELECT 
    `author`.`name`,
    `book`.`title`
FROM `author` INNER JOIN `book` 
     ON `author`.`id` = `book`.`authorId`
     AND ( `author`.`name` = 'search string' OR `book`.`title` = 'search string');
```

The problem here is, if an author has no books, then the result is empty. Even if there is an author that matches the search criteria.

I tried to set the include to `required: false`, which gives a `left outer join`. In that case, I get some not matching results. The where clause is omitted.

How do I have to change my `sequelize` query, or what would be the proper `mysql` query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MySql query should probably be something like

```
SELECT 
    `author`.`name`,
    `book`.`title`
FROM `author` LEFT JOIN `book` 
     ON `author`.`id` = `book`.`authorId`
WHERE ( `author`.`name` = 'search string' OR `book`.`title` = 'search string')
```

Note how here filtering condition is in `WHERE` rather than part of `JOIN ... ON` clause

Basing on the example at [Top level where with eagerly loaded models](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#top-level-where-with-eagerly-loaded-models) you squizzle query should probably be something like

```
Author.findOne({
    where: {
          [Op.or]: [
              {'$author.name$': 'search string'},
              { '$Book.title$': 'search string'}
             ]
           },
    include: [{
        model: Book,           
        required: false
       }]})
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not solve my problem. If the author has no books, your MySQL will give 0 results, even if the search string will match the name of the author. The sequelize statement is also wrong on several points and will not work out for me. The where clause has to be inside the include, otherwise you can not access `Book` in it.

Comment: @henk, have you tried my SQL query against some real data? AFAICS [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5769f/1) it seems to work OK unless I misunderstood your requirements. As for the sequelize query, syntax might be wrong in some details as I haven't tried it but if you look at the [link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#top-level-where-with-eagerly-loaded-models) I referenced in the answer, you'll see that you can put the `where` clause outside of the `include` and still reference the joined table with syntax similar to my query.

Comment: After checking again, in fact, your MySQL statement is right, thanks. The issue was with the `.findOne` It gives a kind of strange MySQL statement, with a `select ... from (select ... as author .. where ...) left outer join ...`. For that reason, the `where` clause outside the `include` will go inside the parentheses, and `books` are not defined there. The solution for now is `.findAll`.  That also misled me while checking your MySQL statement.

Comment: @henk, so does my answer eventually help or doesn't?

Comment: well the problem is solved, so I would say yes :D. Was just thinking if I should leave this open, in case someone can explain the issue behind using `.findOne` and how to use it right for my purpose. But maybe that is another question